# Change "scale" attribute in CSS "transform"

Tags: javascript, css, regex, scale, css-transforms

I have the following `div`

```js
<div style="transform-origin: left top 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, -26px, 0px) scale(1);">
```

As you can see, `transform` contains `scale(1)`. What's the best way to change `scale` value?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, using javascript. There are many ways to do it, I'd do it using a regex.

```
function changeScale(newScale){
    var div = document.getElementById('theID');
    var curTrans = div.style.transform;
    var newScaleString = 'scale(' + newScale + ')';
    var regex = /scale\([0-9|\.]*\)/;
    var newTrans = curTrans.replace(regex, newScaleString);
    div.style.transform = newTrans;
}
```

Or with less lines:

```
function changeScale(newScale){
    var div = document.getElementById('theID');
    div.style.transform = div.style.transform.replace(/scale\([0-9|\.]*\)/, 'scale(' + newScale + ')');
}
```

Comment: @AndiPavllo Great :)

Comment: I've edited it not to repeat the terms "scale(" and ")" manually plus converted it to runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression (assumed you have your div DOM element in a variable 'el' and want to change scale to 2):

```
el.style.transform.replace(/scale\(\d+\)/, 'scale(2)');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36997091/4829915) this one suffers from multiple issues: it doesn't escape string brackets and assumes the scale multiplier is an integer and not floating.

Comment: Thanks for your remark about the brackets, @lwc, I changed that to prevent readers copy&paste wrong code. However, the OP didn't ask for a certain multiplier, but only for replacing the scale.

Comment: Nevertheless, I don't see any advantage.